# mod_rewrite: how to change the url except the homepage?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to do the following:

1. redirect `/about` to `/about.php` (hide the extension)
2. redirect `/(anything else)` to `/content.php?p=(anything else)`
3. while keeping the root `http://domain.com` to `/index.php` (without showing `/index.php`)

I tried this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule "^about$" about.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^((/+[A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ /_content.php?p=$1  [NC,L]
```

It succeeds to achieve the item 1 and 2, but this also rewrites the root `http://domain.com` to `http://domain.com/_content.php?p=`.

What have I done wrong? Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ content.php?p=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What are the differences between `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`? Sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: `REQUEST_FILENAME` points to the actual file that is used for serving the request and `REQUEST_URI` is the request URI that is sent to web server.